ValidationException in DynamoDB or how to send data to DynamoDB table
Well I am kind of newbie developer and just want to share my knowledge with other new developers :)
I was having a problem with sending data from my angular app to DynamoDB, it was constantly showing ValidationException in the browser's console. The same problem and solution is likely to applicable to others platforms and programming languages.
I was watching a lot of videos on youtube and reading others code on github. Finally tonight I've found out how to make resolve that exception and successfully send the data to db.

Here's my own answer:
The reason was that I needed to provide partition key and sort key and they should have correct types (which you can choose only during creation of the table). There is not so obvious details about providing data while sending the data. If you use DynamoDB then you should write your partition key and your sort key and attributes with explicit DinamoDB data types and pass the your item object (Product in my case) as string.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../models/product';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ShopDataService {
  private dynamoDB: AWS.DynamoDB;

  constructor() {
    AWS.config.update({
      region: 'us-east-1',
      accessKeyId: 'myaccesskey',
      secretAccessKey: 'mysecretaccesskey',
    });
    this.dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB();
  }

getProductById(id: number): Observable<Product | null> {
    const item = data.find((item) => item.id === id);
    return item ? of(item) : of(null); // Return product or null when product is not found
  }

  addProduct(product: Product) {
    const params = {
      TableName: 'products',
      Item: {
        id: product.id.toString(),
        shop: product.shop,
        info: product,
      },
    };
    this.dynamoDB.put(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error saving product:', err);
      } else {
        console.log('Product saved successfully:', data);
      }
    });
    // const params = {
    //   TableName: 'products',
    //   Item: { id: {S: product.id.toString()}, shop: {S: product.shop}, text: {S: JSON.stringify(product)} },
    // };
    // this.dynamoDB.putItem(params, (err, data) => {
    //   if (err) {
    //     console.error('Error saving product:', err);
    //   } else {
    //     console.log('Product saved successfully:', data);
    //   }
    // });
  }
}

In case you use DynamoDB's DocumentClient then there is no need to write the partition key and the sort key and attributes with explicit DynamoDB data types, but the data types of the partition key and the sort key should be correct. You can pass your item object without converting it into a string (item would be converted into something like json string but with DynamoDB data types) or as a json string like in the code above (I recommend this option).
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../models/product';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ShopDataService {
  private documentClient: AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient;

  constructor() {
    AWS.config.update({
      region: 'us-east-1',
      accessKeyId: 'myaccesskey',
      secretAccessKey: 'mysecretaccesskey',
    });
    this.documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  }

  addProduct(product: Product) {
    const params = {
      TableName: 'products',
      Item: {
        id: product.id.toString(),
        shop: product.shop,
        info: product,
      },
    };
    this.documentClient.put(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error saving product:', err);
      } else {
        console.log('Product saved successfully:', data);
      }
    });
}

Have a great coding!
